# python can not import tweepy library

Tags: python, tweepy

I tried to import tweepy library but i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

and above in the python file i get this message, i don't know if these two messages are related

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

Comment: The error says you're importing tweedy, not tweepy...

Comment: actually safari correct it to be 'tweedy'. but i import tweepy

Comment: Did you install tweepy? Try `pip install tweepy`

Comment: yes i have installed it

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of python installed. How are you starting python, with python, python3 or something else?

Comment: how can i know if i have multiple versions?

Comment: Which command do you use to start python? Just `python` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have installed tweepy in the right place. Try

```
pip3 install tweepy
```

I had the same problem and this saved it for me.

Comment: I wish I could give you two upvotes for this.  I was going nuts, until I saw this.  Then, I realized that my spyder was running python 3.4 and not 3.5, like I thought it was.  I moved everything over to the python 3.4 folder and everything fell into place.  Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
python -m pip install tweepy
```